# ¿Cómo crear PDF dompdf?

Tags: php

Necesito crear un PDF y almacenarlo en una carpeta del servidor estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/_includes/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

ob_start();
require_once("probando.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/principal/sistema/pdf/dompdf_out.pdf");
$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => true));

exit(0);
?>
```

Con ese código me crea bien el PDF el archivo **probando.php** hago la programación tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
require_once 'controllers/PSController.php';

$fecha_actual   = date("d-m-Y");
$fecha          = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 days")); 
$fecha_7_diasV  = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha."- 6 days")); 

$ps = new PSController();
$maximo  = $ps->HhroughputTotalGBPS();
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="js/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="js/export-data.js"></script>
```

No me genera el PDF me aparece el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function append_child() on a non-object

Comment: Estoy haciendo lo mismo que tu, pero uso [FPDF](http://fpdf.org/?lang=es), hay un tutorial muy simple y la verdad me funciono muy bien. Hasta hay un video que explica como crear un PDF desde un formulario.

Comment: Si, pero FPDF trata asi 

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'¡Hola, Mundo!');
$pdf->Output();

necesito uno que ingrese HTML